# Parsing Gradle project to extract project information (group id, artifact id, version)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-tooling-api

I'm writing a project that requires me to have a Gradle project's version, group id, and artifact id.

I was looking into using something more proper than the solution I have already tried. I have looked into using the Gradle Tooling API. However, it seems like it doesn't provide the project information I need.

Any ideas on how I should go about getting these values properly?

I extracted the project information by parsing the build.gradle & build.gradle.kts files, but it doesn't always work and is a pretty janky solution.